# how the AnnotationAwareOrderComparator works when no bean implements the Ordered interface and no @Order annotation presence

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I trying to find out the answer in chatgpt , so i understand it is determined according to Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE but imagine i have 10 beans how does the container select which bean to take first , second and so on , and attach it Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE ?
also what about "@Configuration" bean ? if i have 10 of them ?
also what is the first type of bean is load?
if i have :

```
@Configuration
public class Conf1 {
}

@Configuration
public class Conf2 {
}

@service
public class Srv1 {
}

@service
public class Srv2 {
}

@Component
public class Com1 {
}
```